# Initialize static final array with indexes

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to initialize a multidimensional private static final array of ints, indexing the values.

```
private static final int[][] a = { {0,0,0}, {1,2,3} };
```

This is NOT good for me.
I found somewhere this weird syntax that I tried, but does not want to compile in anyway. I add it to clarify what I need:

```
private static final int[][] a;
private static {
    a = new int[NUM_TYPES][3];
    a [TYPE_EMPTY]  =   { 0, 0, 0 };
    a [TYPE_NORMAL] =   { 1, 2, 3 };
    };
```

The difference is that now I should have a[TYPE_EMPTY] and a[TYPE_NORMAL] instead of a[0] and a[1]. On the practical side it's the same, but the second one makes much more clear, error-free and maintainable the source.

For example, should I add a new TYPE in future, I would not need to care what numerical index would have inside the array.

As I said, I did not find any correct syntax to do that, and the above syntax is completely wrong.
Would some Java expert give me a short lesson? :)
Thank you very much.

Comment: If your `NUM_TYPES` is fixed to be `2`, then you can simply use `a[0]` and `a[1]`. But what's the problem with first case?

Comment: Can you include the compile error you mention?

Comment: The problem is that I want to initialize expliciting that 0 is TYPE_EMPTY and 1 is TYPE_NORMAL. Obviously this example is very short, I have to deal with much longer arrays.

Comment: @BeppiMenozzi. It seems like you need a `HashMap` here, since you are relating the arrays with some types.

Comment: @Rohit Jain: I'm making this for a matter of performance inside a critical loop, where I want to strongly reduce a switch-case block. I thought that arrays in this case would be much more performant than a HashMap, am I wrong?

Comment: @BeppiMenozzi. If you are mapping those types with some specific array, then you certainly need a `HashMap` rather than defining constants for those types, and using them as indices. Other possibility is to use an `Type` `enum`, and add types to it. And then use a `HashMap<Type, Integer[]>`. But I'm simply shooting in the dark, taking lots of assumptions, just on the basis of what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this -

```
private static final int[][] a;
private static final int NUM_TYPES  = 2;
private static final int TYPE_EMPTY = 0;
private static final int TYPE_NORMAL = 1;

static { // static initializer  block.
    a = new int[NUM_TYPES][3];
    a [TYPE_EMPTY] =  new int[]{ 0, 0, 0 };
    a [TYPE_NORMAL] = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

Reference on [Static initilizing block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: YAY!!! It works, thank you very much Master. Two errors in my code: missing the new for each line and saying that the static block is private.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use enums to hold your data:

```
public enum TYPE {
  TYPE_EMPTY(0,0,0),
  TYPE_NORMAL(1,2,3);

  private int[] data; 

  TYPE(int... data) {
     this.data = data;
  }

  public int[] getData() {
     return data;
  }
}
```

You can get an array of all enum instances by using `TYPE.values()`.

**Reasoning:** I think if you have already *names* for your data rows, they actually *mean* something for you, so they deserve to be real objects. If you have a small set of "constant" instances, then enums are a good choice. This design gives you much more flexibility (you can make a defensive copy of the data array, add new attributes, you can add, rearrange or remove enum instances etc without breaking anything).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see `private static final int ...` defining hard offsets etc. I try to think of a way of using `enums` to solve the problem because - after all - that is what they are.

I came up with this:

```
enum MyType {
  Empty(null),
  Normal(new int[] {1,2,3});
  // My values.
  final int [] values;
  // Constructor.
  MyType(int [] values) {
    this.values = values;
  }

  // Getter - equivalent to the array access.
  public int get(int i) {
    return values == null ? 0 : values[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops - I see [Landei](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14850452/823393) has done something similar.